# How to start a new line when it senses certain word in R?

Tags: r

So i have a text like below:

```
"Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd Speaker 1: sjdakldak Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak Speaker 1: sjdaskd. "
```

What are some functions that i could use to start a new line whenever a new speaker is speaking? The final outcome should be

```
"Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn 
Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd 
Speaker 1: sjdakldak 
Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak 
Speaker 1: sjdaskd."
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create the newline with `gsub` and print with `cat`

```
cat(gsub("\\s(\\w+\\s+\\d+:)", "\n\\1", str1, perl = TRUE), '\n')
#Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn
#Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd
#Speaker 1: sjdakldak
#Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak
#Speaker 1: sjdaskd.
```

---

Or after inserting the newline, read it with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = gsub("\\s(\\w+\\s+\\d+:)", "\n\\1", str1), header = FALSE, sep=",")
#                        V1
#1 Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn
#2   Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd
#3     Speaker 1: sjdakldak
#4    Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak
#5     Speaker 1: sjdaskd.
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd Speaker 1: sjdakldak Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak Speaker 1: sjdaskd. "
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always has keyword like `Speak*`, maybe we can try

```
cat(gsub("\\s(Speak.*?)","\n\\1",s),"\n")
```

such that

```
> cat(gsub("\\s(Speak.*?)","\n\\1",s),"\n")
Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn
Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd
Speaker 1: sjdakldak
Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak
Speaker 1: sjdaskd.
```

**Data**

```
s <- "Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd Speaker 1: sjdakldak Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak Speaker 1: sjdaskd. "
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how closely you want to match the initial keywords. You can adjust the regular expression to be more or less strict.

```
strsplit(s,'\\s+(?=Speak(er)? \\d+:)',perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_replace_all` from `stringr`. Taking the string `s` from @ThomasIsCoding

```
cat(stringr::str_replace_all(s, '(Speak)', '\n\\1'))

#Speaker 1: dasjkdasldasn 
#Speaker 2: sadjasdkasd 
#Speaker 1: sjdakldak 
#Speak 2: sjdlaksdlsak 
#Speaker 1: sjdaskd.
```